# Require code review (even of users with admin privileges) in gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I work on a small team of 4 contributing to a number of internal gitlab repos.  We are all 'masters' of the repos and thus can push to protected branches.  What I cannot figure out, though, is how to require a code review (either directly on a pull request, or eventually through hooks to an external system) for pushes to a protected branch by someone with full or partial administrative privileges to a repo.

to ask the question more directly: can gitlab be configured to require a repo owner/master get code review approval (through pull requests or otherwise) from another owner/master before they are able to push?

Comment: So and whats your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Gerrit work in front of Gitlab or is it meant to replace it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25880670/can-gerrit-work-in-front-of-gitlab-or-is-it-meant-to-replace-it)

Comment: agreed, this is a duplicate, and the answer to that question answers this.